# Disappear Standard Error in OxEdit/G@rch6 package

Tags: r, garch, ox

Hellow everyone, I'm new here. Please instruct me to do something.

My problem is when I run FIGARCH(0,d,1), OxEdit still show me a matrix with variable names, coefficient, s.e, t-stat... like this

[image]

But when I try FIGARCH(1,d,2) it show nothing but coefficient parameters, like this

[image]

So please instruct me how to show the other stats.

Furthermore, please instruct me how to run G@rch6 package in R via function GarchOxFit, because this function is no longer supported but Mr. Brian in [this topic](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8667/garchoxfit-in-r) show that R can run G@rch6.

I much appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, as it is written in your example, the FIGARCH(1,d,2) estimation fails due to "*no convergence*" : ie the quasi Maximum Likelihood Estimation Method fails to obtain stable parameters via the maximization of the likelihood and so you can't get parameters for this specification (neither other stats). The QMLE method does not always get result.